# htaccess 301 redirect only certain URL with exlusion

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

how to write the rule to redirect only certain URL and ignore redirect if exist something after that

EG

there is a link

/catalog/product/view/id/1144/s/some-data/category it should go to the example.com

so will be

```
Redirect 301 /catalog/product/view/id/1144/s/some-data/category https://example.com/
```

this works well for this case, but for the case /catalog/product/view/id/1144/s/some-data/category/214 it redirect to the https://example.com//214, but i don't need to redirect this, should ignore.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match **exact** URL you need to use `RedirectMatch` instead of `Redirect` with regex capabilities and anchors:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/catalog/product/view/id/1144/s/some-data/category/?$ https://example.com/
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.